# How to fix 'Bad-Request', empty body when logging exceptions to sentry (php sdk)

Tags: php, sentry, bad-request

I have migrated from the old sentry SDK to the new Unified PHP SDK. Since then exceptions and errors are not logged to sentry and I get a Bad Request response.

I know this question is rather vague and open, but I mainly want to know if there are any known potential issues or if someone can point me in the correct direction to investigate further.

This is for PHP 7.3.7 running Wordpress 5.2 and Sentry SDK 2.1.2
It is a default implementation, no changes to Transport and we do not use any integrations. The error occurs in Sentry\Transport\HttpTransport::cleanupPendingRequests after WP has run its shutdown hook after an error has been triggered.

If I log messages manually to Sentry it works (most of the time? Just had one occurrence where it did not work just now...). But sending exceptions to sentry when they are thrown does not. The request is set up to be sent via a promise in sentry with the correct data, but finally, I get a Bad Request response back.

Since implementing the unifiened SDK we have had two calls to sentry that actually made it through, but I know there should be many more (sadly).

Looking at the request and building a curl command from it and running it works as expected.

(We also use the Javascript Browser SDK. That works as it should)

```php
Sentry\init([
            "dsn" => "__dsn__"]);

// works 
Sentry\captureMessage("Hello", Sentry\Severity::debug);

// Will eventually end up returning a Bad Request response
throw new \Exception(":(");
```

I expect the Exception thrown in the example to end up in Sentry, but instead, I get a Bad Request Response.

Comment: Can you update your deps and make sure you have `2.1.3` we fixed a bug regarding this in there.

Comment: Thanks @HazA . Looks like that was the issue. Would be great if you updated the SDK to use sentry/sentry:2.1.3 as I have to depend on dev-master right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HazA pointed out, it was a bug in the sentry/sentry package fixed in version 2.1.3